# Unable to convert XML to C# Object List

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.5

I'm trying to convert the XML data to an object list, but it throws an error.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Servers>
  <Server>
    <ServerName>STAGING</ServerName>
    <ServerIP>XXX.XXX.XX.X</ServerIP>        
  </Server>
</Servers>
```

**C#**

```
public class ServerDetails
{
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string ServerIP { get; set; }        
}

private void GetXMLData()
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ServerDetails>));

  using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("D:\\Resource.xml"))
  {
    List<ServerDetails> list = (List<ServerDetails>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    //Exception here
  }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Inner Exception : <Servers xmlns=''> was not expected.   
There is an error in XML document (2,2)
```

I tried adding the `[Serializabe]` and `[XMLElement]` attributes to the class,
and also `xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsd/ServerDetails"` in the XML
but that did not help.

Comment: You can analyze the problems by first serialize an object first and view the resulting XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XmlElement Notation to specify the element name.

```
public class Servers
{        
    [XmlElement("Server")]
    public ServerDetails[] ServersDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ServerDetails
{
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string ServerIP { get; set; }
}


private void GetXMLData()
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Servers));

  using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("D:\\Resource.xml"))
  {
    Servers list = (Servers)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    //Exception here
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the code is the same, It's working fine for me, see demo at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7JCmcX

Answer (score 2):

You have ServerDetails as your class name and in the xml the tag name is different, Try something like this.

```
public class ServerDetails
{
   public string ServerName { get; set; }
   public string ServerIP { get; set; }        
}

public class ServerList
{
   [XmlArray("Servers")]
   [XmlArrayItem("Server", Type = typeof(ServerDetails))]
   public ServerDetails[] Servers { get;set;}        
}

private void GetXMLData()
{
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServerList));

   using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("D:\\Resource.xml"))
   {
      var list = (ServerList)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
      //Exception here
   }
}
```

Comment: It's the same exception still.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use `XmlSerializer` a lot, but I totally stopped using it because you are forced to create your object structure fitting the xml structure. That makes it hard to maintain. Also `XmlSerializer` has some serious memory leaks.

If you don't mind, I would suggest to switch to `XElement`

```
    public IEnumerable<ServerDetails> GetServers(string file)
    {
        using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            return GetServers(stream);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ServerDetails> GetServers(Stream stream)
    {
        var root = XElement.Load(stream);
        return GetServers(root);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ServerDetails> GetServers(XElement root)
    {
        foreach (var server in root.Elements("Server"))
        {
            yield return new ServerDetails
            {
                ServerName = (string)server.Element("ServerName"),
                ServerIP = (string)server.Element("ServerIP"),
            };
        }
    }
```

Please note that you have to reference `System.Xml.Linq`

For your convenience here is a test case.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanReadServers()
    {
        var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" + @"
<Servers>
  <Server>
    <ServerName>STAGING</ServerName>
    <ServerIP>XXX.XXX.XX.X</ServerIP>
  </Server>
</Servers>";

        IEnumerable<ServerDetails> servers;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
            servers = GetServers(stream).ToList();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, servers.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual("STAGING", servers.ElementAt(0).ServerName);
        Assert.AreEqual("XXX.XXX.XX.X", servers.ElementAt(0).ServerIP);
    }
```